# Iron router with Meteor display data to template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am using iron router with Meteor (latest versions). I have a template:

```
<template name="home">
    {{#each products}}
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
    JJJJJJJJJJJJ
</template>
```

and in `lib/router.js`:

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate:'layout'
});

Router.map(function () {
   this.route('home', {
   path:'/',
   template:'home',
   data : function () {
              return Products.find();
          }
   });
});
```

When I run the page, I see empty page with this `JJJJJJJJJJJJ`, added for test to see is it template loads.
In the Products collection are 2 items with `name`. I can read (select), add, remove items for this collection via WEB browser console, but the collection is not rendered in the template.
What can  be the error ?

Comment: Using `data:` you set the context of your template, which means `this` of your template becomes yours cursor. So `Products.find()` have no `products` field. Try something like `{{#each this}}`.

Answer (score 3):

The `data` function of Iron Router sets the **data context** for the template. In your case, you are setting the data context to be a cursor but attempting to access the cursor with `products`, which does not exist as a helper, either registered globally or on the template itself.

There's a few ways you can fix this, but I would suggest letting the router simply determine which template to render and let the template fetch it's own data.

Adjusted router:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home'
  }
);
```

Template helper:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  products() {
    return Products.find();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `this` keyword within the template to access the current data context:

```
<template name="home">
  {{#each this}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
  {{/each}}
  JJJJJJJJJJJJ
</template>
```

However, it is not easy to discern what is being put into `this` unless you can follow the flow of the data through the route to the template. This also couples this template very tightly with this route, as the route itself is determining the context of your template.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in `lib/router.js`, need to set attribute `data` like this :

```
data : function () {
           templateData = {
               products: Products.find()
           };
           return templateData;
       }
```

, NOT like before - `return Products.find();` .